# 'Invoke' and 'BeginInvoke' are called but never resolved

Tags: c#, message-queue, invoke, invokerequired, message-pump

I am taking care of the GUI thread of a piece of software. I have to display inside a GridView data that needs to be constantly polled from the underlying APIs. I created a method called `Sync()` which updates the data, and I tried to make it thread safe by using `BeginInvoke` and/or `Invoke`. The `Sync` method is called by a timer every five seconds or so.

The body of `Sync` is never called, as for some reason it seems that my request is never pulled from the message pump. The code:

```
 public void Sync()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            logger.Debug("Begin Invoke of Sync operation");
            this.Invoke(new SyncDelegate(Sync));
            logger.Debug("End Invoke of Sync operation");
        }
        else
        {
            logger.Debug("Inside body");
        }

    }
```

The log looks like:

```
10:00:00 Begin Invoke of Sync operation
... other stuff ...
10:00:05 Begin Invoke of Sync operation
... other stuff ...
10:00:10 Begin Invoke of Sync operation
```

The other messages are never printed.

The same for `BeginInvoke`. "End Invoke ... " is printed but "inside body ..." is never printed.

I'm running on top of Unity3D and MonoDevelop (if this changes anything).

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Apparently I was creating the Windows Form outside of the Application.Run command. 
For some reason instantiating the Form inside the Application.Run comand did the trick